# Surface bounded by a cylinder and two planes

Tags: calculus

Consider the closed volume V contained by the cylinder $x^2 +z^2 = 4 $ and the planes $y=-2$ and $x+y=3$ Let the surface S be the boundary of this region. Find a parametric representation for each for each of the three parts of S. I am thinking $x=u$ and $y=v$ with $z=\sqrt{4-u^2}$. I am confused on what "find the surface area element" means.

Answer (score 1):

I was just going to comment with a hint, but apparently I don't have enough rep for that yet...

As mentioned in the question the surface 'S' can be broken up into three parts; a circular base (where the cylinder intersects the plane y = -2), a circular top (where the cylinder intersects the plane x + y = 3 and finally the original side of the cylinder (minus the sections sliced away by the planes.

The circular base of the cylinder, where y = -2, is a circle (centred at the origin and with a radius of 2) in the x-z plane and as such one possible parameterisation is:

$x(r,t) = rcos(t) \\
y(r,t) = -2 \\
z(r,t) = rsin(t)$

Where 'r' is the distance of the point (x, y, z) from the origin of the circle, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$

A similar line of reasoning will help you find the parameterisation of the circular region formed by the intersection of the cylinder and the plane $x + y = 3$. (That it's a <strike>circle</strike> is the hint, hopefully something you'll be able to confirm when you find the curve defined by the intersection of the plane and the cylinder)

As for the third part of the surface area you should be able to re-use one of the parameterisations for the circular regions and just take a note of the possible values of x and z. (hint: they're on a cylinder)

Let me know if I've messed up or been unclear. =]

Edit: Whoever said that the intersection of the plane $x + y = 3$ and the cylinder is a circle was certainly wrong... I'll sit down now.

Comment: Actually $x+y=3$ will be an ellipse won't it?  It cuts obliquely through the cylinder.

Comment: I initially thought so to, but when I did the algebra I ended up with a circle. Someone should probably double check me since I can't find a mistake in my algebra (not to say it's not there) but I did want to leave my answer as a starting point and not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest segment is the $y=-2$ circle, with $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le r \le 2$, at $(r \cos \theta, -2, r \sin \theta)$, ranging over $r$ and $\theta$.  You could also do it with $-2 \le x \le 2$ and $-1 \le u \le 1$, at $(x, -2, u\sqrt{4 - x^2})$, ranging over $x$ and $u$.

The other end is a little trickier.  We still have $-2 \le x \le 2$.  The $y$ is a function of $x$ since $y = 3 - x$.  So define $-1 \le u \le 1$ and $(x, 3-x, u\sqrt{4 - x^2})$ ranging over $x$ and $u$ covers the other end.

The total cylinder is covered by $(2 \cos \theta, y, 2 \sin \theta)$ with $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.  But we need to restrict the y range to go between $y=-2$ and $y = 3 - x = 3 - 2 \cos \theta$ for any given $\theta$, so the total length will be $5 - 2 \cos \theta$.  So the parameterization will be $(2 \cos \theta, -2 + u(5 - 2 \cos \theta), 2 \sin \theta)$ over $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le u \le 1$.